# How to locate blob edges

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to find a way to locate the edges of some blobs I have in a BW image. Do you know if Matlab has some function able to a) put a blob in a rectangle and b) find the coordinates of the rectangle's sides?

Comment: Look into `regionprops` for `BoundingBox` [Link](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#bqkf8hf) ?

Comment: yepp it looks the solution is somewhere there. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be self-contained, and to carry on with Divakar's comment, let's do this with an example.  You can certainly use the `BoundingBox` property with `regionprops`.  For each blob that has been detected using `regionprops`, the `BoundingBox` property will return a bounding box that encompasses each blob.  For each blob, we will have a `1 x 4` array that is structured like so:

```
[x y w h]
```

`x,y` denote the **column** (`x` co-ordinate) and **row** (`y` co-ordinate) of the upper left corner of the rectangle and `w,h` denote the width and height of the rectangle itself.  We can work with an example image given in MATLAB's system path: `text.png`.  This is what the image looks like:

```
im = imread('text.png');
imshow(im);
```

[image]

In this case, each "blob" would be a letter in the image (or a character).  We can then get the bounding boxes like so:

```
s = regionprops(im, 'BoundingBox');
rects = reshape([s.BoundingBox], 4, []).';
```

`rects` will contain a `N x 4` matrix, where each row is a rectangle for each blob we have.  The reshaping has to be done because this is the only way of extracting the rectangles from a structure array in a vectorized manner.

Now that you have this, it's very simple to iterate over our list of co-ordinates and place rectangles around each blob.  I'm going to put a yellow rectangle so you can see them.  You can do this by using the [`rectangle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) command, by specifying the `Position` flag as the first element, and using the 4 element array for each blob that we just talked about.  As such:

```
imshow(im);
hold on;
for idx = 1 : numel(s)
    rectangle('Position', rects(idx,:), 'EdgeColor', 'yellow');
end
```

This is what I get:

[image]